# How many of the 26 reincarnators are known and what are their status at the time of the S series?

Tags: so-im-a-spider-so-what

In the Kumo storyline, 26 creatures reincarnated:

> 24 students, 1 teacher and 1 spider (that received the human memories of the 26th student, that was Admin D in disguise).

Besides the eponymous protagonist, who where the others, and how are them at the time of the S series?

Answer (score 4):

I assume by S series you mean the side stories which start off with the reincarnated babies. Since several events changed over time, this summary skips their childhoods, but will not go into details about the major story events that happened as they are teenagers to avoid major spoilers.

For manga readers at least, this will be full of spoilers from the light/web novel. The spoiler tags only hold very minor spoilers except the last few. If you watched several anime episodes or read several volumes of the light novel they are not spoilers.

4 of them

> died while young and are not important to the story.

2 of them

> were born in the major kingdom Analeit. The first being Shun a prince and younger brother of the one with the hero title, and the other Katia, the boy (Kanata) who reincarnated as a girl.

Another one was

> Hugo, born as the next in line for the strongest swordsman, a Prince of the Renxandt Empire

And all 3 above were sent to the same school, along with the Teacher (Filimos/Oka), who

> was born as an elf, the child of the leader of the elves.

One more also attended the school

> Yuri who was orphaned to the church and became a potential Saint Candidate.

A change from the Web Novel to the Light Novel (which the Anime and Manga are based off of) had 1 more attend the school

> Feirune, the girl reincarnated as an Earth Wyrm and who is blending in as Shuns familiar.

2 were

> born in a small village and became adventurers together after it was destroyed and everyone else killed. Eventually as teenagers they were collected by the elves and joined the 11 below

11 (12 in the web novel) were

> picked up, bought, or kidnapped by the elves and raised in their village, isolated from the world.

The last 3 here are encroaching in real spoiler territory as their backstories play an important role in the plot and the last 2 are not even revealed yet at all after 20 Anime episodes.

Sophia was

> born in a town as a progenitor vampire, to the local Lord of the land.

1 more was

> Found by the Church and became one of its elite operatives.

The last one was

> Was born as a goblin.

Somewhat major spoiler on what happened to 2 of those 3

> Sophia and the Goblin went through some major spoiler events and eventually joined the Demons as elite operatives

That is all 26 reincarnations in their early life excluding our Protagonist.

Comment: you are forgetting the 3 that were taken in by the Church, 1 girl that ended up being regarded as a Saint, and 2 boys, one was a ninja and the other was a seemingly normal kid, but had a long distance communication skill so he was planted at the elf village as a spy by the Church. There's also the LN exclusive girl that was reborn as a dragon and ended up as the Prince's pet.

Comment: The church boy in the elf village was included "Like one from the church", but I didn't point out spoilers part there. I indeed don't recall the 2 others though

Comment: Decided to update and fix the answer since the old one was pretty bad and no new answers showed up.